# compare strings at being typed

Tags: javascript

I'm having some difficulty with a string comparison function.  I have a textbox that has a keyup event.  when a key is pressed, it calls a function to compare what is in the text box with a list of values.  I want to be able to allow the user to type a word in the box and eliminate choices from the list that are not compatible with what has been typed.  For instance, if i had this list:

```
   jay
   jason
   jamie
   jamu
   jenny
   sara
```

and allowed the user to type:

```
   'j' --> sara should be eleminated as a choice
   'ja' --> sara and jenny should be eliminated
   'jam' --> only jamie and jamu should be left
   'jamu' --> should only leave jamu
```

the code I have only seems to to it letter by letter and and not cumulatively.  Does anyone have any suggestions for a better way to check strings?

thanks

```
         function filterByName(e){
        var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
    fullString=fullString + keychar
             ..... some other stuff
            //iterate over list
            var ul = document.getElementById("friendUl");           
    var liNodes = ul.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
    var nodeLength = liNodes.length

    for (i=0;i<=nodeLength-1;i++){

            var getFNames=  document.getElementsByName('fNames').item(i)
    var getLNames =  document.getElementsByName('lNames').item(i)
    var fullNames = getFNames + " " + getLNames

    for (j=0;j<=fullString.length-1;j++){
       if(fullString.charAt(j)== fullNames.charAt(j)){
           alert(fullNames)
       }
    }
         }
     }
```

'

Comment: Use  `Array.filter` and `String.indexOf` combinedly to get it done. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just want to see if the given name starts with the value of `fullString`.

```
if (fullName.indexOf(fullString) === 0) {
  // It's still valid
} else {
  // It's not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function off of string like this:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(val) {
  return 0 == this.indexOf(val);
};
```

And use that instead of your for loop where you are using `charAt()`.  Specifically, replace this:

```
for (j=0;j<=fullString.length-1;j++){
       if(fullString.charAt(j)== fullNames.charAt(j)){
           alert(fullNames)
       }
    }
```

With this:

```
if (fullNames.startsWith(fullString))
   alert(fullNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing

```
fullString=fullString + keychar
```

you should be doing

```
fullstring = document.getElementById('TextBoxId').value;
```

this way, you account for backspaces, etc...